# CoreML, Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, coreml

I'm in the process of building the data sets of plants. I'm planning on having around 30-40 images per asset, but I need some information on how many plants I can add to the model before it gets too big for an iOS app. Could anyone provide me with some information on how many plant species could be added to the model if we are training each species with 30-40 images?

Answer (score 0):

The number of training images has no effect on the size of the model.

The number of classes (different plant species) has only a tiny effect on the size of the model, especially if you plan to train it using Create ML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my findings are also the same as i did some R&D on that